# Relatively Referencing Observations in a function in R

Tags: r, function, if-statement, missing-data

When writing a function that calculates each observation in a vector, how do I reference said observation to include cells of observations that are a pre-determined number of observations away from the observation currently being operated on? If each row is i, such that i = 1, 2, ..., etc., how do I reference a column in row i-1?

Here is a sample data-set that mimics my dilemma:

```
> letters <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'e')
> numbers <- c('1', '', '2', '', '3')
> sample <- cbind(letters, numbers)
> sample
     letters numbers
[1,] "a"     "1"    
[2,] "b"     ""     
[3,] "c"     "2"    
[4,] "b"     ""     
[5,] "e"     "3"
```

I would like to fill each empty cell in `sample$numbers` with the value in `sample$numbers` from the observation prior. How do I reference the observation being created in its creation? For example, I've tried:

```
> sample$numbers <- ifelse(sample$numbers == "", sample$numbers[as.numeric(rownames(sample)) - 1], sample$numbers)
Error in sample$numbers : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

I've also tried using the common `b` in `sample$letters` to fill the missing value:

```
> f1 <- function(df, cols, match_with, to_x = 'b'){
+   df[cols] <- lapply(df[cols], function(i) 
+     ifelse(grepl(to_x, match_with, fixed = TRUE), sample$numbers[as.numeric(rownames(sample)) - 1], 
+            i))
+   return(df)
+ }
> sample = f1(sample, cols = c('numbers'), match_with = sample$letters)
 Hide Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error in sample$letters : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors 
5.
grepl(to_x, match_with, fixed = TRUE) 
4.
ifelse(grepl(to_x, match_with, fixed = TRUE), sample$numbers[as.numeric(rownames(sample)) - 
    1], i) 
3.
FUN(X[[i]], ...) 
2.
lapply(df[cols], function(i) ifelse(grepl(to_x, match_with, fixed = TRUE), 
    sample$numbers[as.numeric(rownames(sample)) - 1], i)) 
1.
f1(sample, cols = c("numbers"), match_with = sample$letters)
```

My trouble seems to be, in both cases, that I'm using `sample$numbers[as.numeric(rownames(sample)) - 1]` to reference `sample$numbers`'s value in the previous observation. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `$` only works on `list` or `data.frame`, not `matrix`. You can refer to that column with `sample[, 2]` or `sample[, "numbers"]`.  I would try: `sample[, 2] <- ifelse(sample[, 2] == '', c('', head(sample[, 2], -1)), sample[, 2])`.

Comment: Have a look at the `FillDown` function from the `DataCombine` package. Here is a [link](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/DataCombine/versions/0.2.21/topics/FillDown)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sample[,"numbers"] <- sapply(seq_along(sample[,"numbers"]), 
                             function(x) ifelse(sample[,"numbers"][x] == '', 
                                                sample[,"numbers"][x-1], 
                                                sample[,"numbers"][x]))

     letters numbers
[1,] "a"     "1"    
[2,] "b"     "1"    
[3,] "c"     "2"    
[4,] "b"     "2"    
[5,] "e"     "3"
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a data.frame and not a matrix which you used above (in order to be able to reference columns with `$`) you could use `zoo::na.locf` for this:

```
#make a data.frame instead of a matrix
sample <- data.frame(letters, numbers)

library(zoo)
#if your data has '' empty cells then convert those to NA
sample$numbers[sample$numbers == ''] <- NA
sample$numbers <- na.locf(sample$numbers)
```

Output:

```
sample
  letters numbers
1       a       1
2       b       1
3       c       2
4       b       2
5       e       3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `FillDown` function from the `DataCombine` package:

```
library(DataCombine)
letters <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'e')
numbers <- c('1', '', '2', '', '3')
numbers[numbers==""] <- NA # replace empty strings with NA
sample <- data.frame(letters,numbers)

FillDown(sample,"numbers")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
letters <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'e')
numbers <- c('1', '', '2', '', '3')
sample <- data.frame(letters, numbers, stringsAsFactors = F)


sample$numbers[sample$numbers == ""] <- c(sample$numbers[2:nrow(sample)], NA)[sample$numbers == ""]
```